# Proving AVL trees can have children whose number of nodes aren't Θ of one another

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, fibonacci, avl-tree, big-o

Let T be an AVL tree whose left subtree is T<sub>L</sub> and whose right subtree is T<sub>R</sub>. Let's let |T<sub>L</sub>| and |T<sub>R</sub>| be the number of nodes in the left and right subtrees, respectively.

I need to prove that neither |T<sub>R</sub>| ≠ Θ(|T<sub>R</sub>|) and vice-versa but I don't know how. I assume it has to do with the case where one tree is a full AVL tree and the other is a minimal AVL tree (a Fibonacci tree), but I don't know what to do from there.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, the depth of the left and the right subtree of the root of an AVL tree differs at most one. This property is an invariant that is maintained by the rebalancing operations during node insertion and deletion.

Comment: You just need a family of AVL trees where the quotient |TL| / |TR| tends to zero or infinity

Answer (score 1):

In an AVL tree of height h, the number of nodes ranges between F<sub>h+2</sub> - 1 and 2<sup>h</sup> - 1. This first quantity is Θ(φ<sup>h</sup>) and the second is Θ(2<sup>h</sup>), where φ is the golden ratio, approximately 1.61. This means that you can construct AVL trees where the number of nodes in the left subtree is Θ(φ<sup>h</sup>) and the right subtree is Θ(2<sup>h</sup>), meaning that the left subtree has asymptotically fewer nodes than the right subtree. You can then reverse left and right to show that the right subtree can't be Θ of the left subtree either.

Hope this helps!